# How to scroll the Div automatically in C# selenium webdriver?

Tags: c#

I used "sendkeys(keys.pagedown)" but i need to scroll the Div list with height. like scroll-Top in Java script.
Is there any possibilities to scroll?

My code is:

```
driver.FindElementByClassName("body").SendKeys(Keys.PageDown);
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not use code with SendKeys(Keys.PageDown); for scroll.

But I know javascript code for the scroll.

I have use this line of code for scrolling page.

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,400)", "");
```

This will scroll your page by 400 points. You can increase it.

There is also different flavor are available for this JS, specially for scroll.

### Enjoy it.

---

I am not using C# code for selenium script so I have written code in JAVA. Please change it according as per your language.

Take the another way If you have elements in your HTML DOM.

If you have HTML element of your Dragger bar then you can write code like this

```
public static boolean scroll_Page(WebElement webelement, int scrollPoints){
Action dragger = new Actions(driver);
int numberOfPixelsToDragTheScrollbarDown = 10;
    for (int i = 10; i < scrollPoints; i = i + numberOfPixelsToDragTheScrollbarDown){
       dragger.moveToElement(webelement).clickAndHold().moveByOffset(0, numberOfPixelsToDragTheScrollbarDown).release(webelement).build().perform();
    }
}
```

You can create method like this.
Pass dragger element and scroll points.

Try this.

Comment: I am having two scroll bars in my page. And want to mention which scroll bar. Both scroll bars in Div tag. How can I mention the div?I have class name for those scrollbars.

Comment: Thanks for helping me. This answer does not suits to my language. Thanks a lot.

Comment: As I know Actions class functionality supported by selenium in C#. So you can use this method. Rather than any problem with code you can comment me.

Answer (score 0):

Use `element.scrollIntoView()` method of element object in JavaScript. The signature of the method is `element.scrollIntoView(alignWithTop)`

Good article
http://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/scroll-element-view-selenium-javascript/